# Why does Resharper complain about "Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute" for Worksheet objects but not for the others?

Tags: c#, excel-interop, worksheet, comobject, resharper-10.0

I've got this code to release some COM Objects in an Excel Interop app:

```
    . . .
    }
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlSheet);

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlSheets);

    _xlBook.Close(false, null, null);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlBook);

    _xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    _xlApp.Quit();
    OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
} // foreach (DataRowView drv in selectedUnits)
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlApp);
```

In another place I also release the sheet used there:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlSheetDelPerf);
```

This all works just fine, but a Resharper Inspect > Code Issues in Solution unearths "*Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute*" on the two ReleaseComObject() calls to the Excel.Worksheet objects (but not to the Sheet, Workbook, or Application objects). They are defined like so:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
. . .
private Excel.Application _xlApp;
private Excel.Workbook _xlBook;
private Excel.Sheets _xlSheets;
private Excel.Worksheet _xlSheet;
private Excel.Worksheet _xlSheetDelPerf;
```

What makes Worksheet so [un]special? More importantly, should I remove the ReleaseComObject() code for them? And use something else instead to release them?

**Note:** The accepted answer to the question "*How to properly clean up Excel interop objects*" by VVS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects), with 474 upvotes, *does* show a sheet being released this way...?!?

### UPDATE

Okay, I followed MethodMan's advice (who wouldn't, with a moniker like that?) and now I have:

```
            // Free up resources
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlSheet);

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlSheets);

            _xlBook.Close(false, null, null);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlBook);

            _xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            _xlApp.Quit();

            _xlSheet = null;
            _xlSheets = null;
            _xlBook = null;
        } //if (_xlSheet != null)
        OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    } // foreach (DataRowView drvu in selectedUnits)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlApp);
    _xlApp = null;
} // try
finally
{
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: you should be doing this for all the ComInterop objects 
`Marshal.ReleaseComObject` also set the object `= null;` then you can have a Finally block and call `GC.Collect`

Comment: If I should be doing this for all the ComInterop objects (which includes Worksheet), why does Resharper single that object out in this way?